# Get excel column as array NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I have an excel sheet that updates daily, and I need to extract the last element of specific columns. I am using the XLSX node module, but cant find any way to read specific columns in my sheet.

This is what I had in mind:

```
var wb = XLSX.readFile("test.xlsx", { cellDates: true });
var ws = wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
const colArray = ws["B"]; //To get column B as an array
```

Anyone with a solution to this? Preferably with the XLSX module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
//Create an array with the object keys and filter "B" columns. Assign it to the variable "columnB"
let columnB = Object.keys(ws).filter(key => key[0] === "B");

//Get the last key name in your columnB variable.Assign it to the "lastElementKey" variable.
let lastElementKey = columnB[columnB.length -1];

//And lastly, this is your last element in column "B"
ws[lastElementKey]
```